# Example of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

$f$ is continuously differentiable function on $\Bbb R$

Define $f_n(x)=\dfrac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$

I want example of function such that $f_n\to f'$ but not uniformly on $\Bbb R$

I thought that above $f_n$ converges uniformly but this is not correct. Please can anyone help me to find example

where is my intitution going wrong?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't $f(x)=x^3$ work?

Comment: Because that $f_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)=3x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{3x}{n^2}$. And the term $\frac{3x}{n^2}$ is not uniformly convergent.

Comment: If the derivative is uniformly continuous then this convergence must be uniform. Since you specified that $f$ has a continuous derivative, the counterexample must be where that continuity is not uniform. @yoyo gives a good example.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested target.

Comment: @RRL Thank you~!!

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 No, this is not a duplicate of that at all, it's a totally different question.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My bad.  I omitted the $'$.  Close vote retracted,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3$. Then it will be an example.

Since $f_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)=3x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{3x}{n}$. But the term $\frac{3x}{n}$ is not convergent uniformly to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.